# Two users with the same 'home' folder but different '.profiles'

Tags: home, profile, access-control, accounts, multiuser

I would like to have at least two users signing in the same home folder, so them need to have full access to this folder, but with different 'profile' behavior.

**host-foo:**

- **user1** : `/home/foo-folder -> .profile -> exec foo-program`
- **user2** : `/home/foo-folder -> .profile -> shell`

**host-bar -** Need access to `/home/foo-folder` on `host-foo` without password:

```
ssh user2@host-foo ls
```

Each one user needs to have different 'profiles' (or something like that), where one cannot have access to the shell, so he'll have a program being auto-run at login (eg: exec foo-program, in .profile), and the other one user needs direct access to the shell prompt.

The other aspect is the need to authorize the 'user with shell access' to sign in without password through ssh. Keep in mind that ssh requires home folder to deny write access on 'group' and 'others' permissions. So, I cannot have two users expanding permissions to group.

Is this possible ? How ?

Comment: use $LOGNAME var and an if-then-else ?

Comment: Why have the same directory? Seems rather unnecessary and better just to give them their own directory for them to arrange and use without the other person trampling over them

Comment: @EdHeal: I need two ways to sign in to the same folder, one will auto-run a program, another one a shell access.

Comment: Cannot think of why you need to sign into the same directory?

Comment: I have a system that is launched by exec in .profile, so our users just access the system without shell access. But we need also, a way to access the shell, without a lot of workaround, since this folder need also to be accessed by 'robots' remotely without password by ssh. (it's a legacy curses/terminal based system)

Comment: You could add a second user with the same uid as the first, but with a different home directory.

Comment: Is user1 accessing host-foo via ssh or by logging in on the console?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: Doesn't matter, since we have two ways to access the same folder tree with the same permissons: One way by the system (program auto executed by login), and another one by shell, bypassing the exec statement in .profile.

Comment: OK. If you currently have two ways to access the folder tree with the same permissions, then could you specify what the remaining problem is?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, I haven't it, I need it. That is que question, how to ?

Comment: Does the .profile of user1 do anything besides an `exec`?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: basic settings like definition of some env vars, and customized PATH.

Comment: Then @archemar's and @andyDalton's suggestions together would work. Keep in mind that, in any case, `ssh user1@host-foo arbitrary-command` will not run any of the commands in .profile. And in the case of a normal login, user1 can also type `^C` quickly to avoid the `exec`, so there isn't much security against preventing user1 from running arbitrary commands. If user1 accesses host-foo only via ssh (see my previous comment), there is a way for force it to run a specific command and not a full shell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27050/discussion-between-luciano-and-mark-plotnick).